# Change pool size in SupervisionGroup

Tags: ruby, celluloid

Can I change pool size in celluloid supervision group?

For example I have a worker:

```
class Worker 
  include Celluloid

  def do
    puts self.inspect
  end
end
```

And then I provision 3 workers in a supervision group:

```
supervisor = Celluloid::SupervisionGroup.run!
supervisor.pool(Worker, size: 3, as: :worker)
```

Can I somehow modify the pool size in `supervisor`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found it:

```
supervisor = Celluloid::SupervisionGroup.run!
pool = supervisor.pool(Worker, size: 3, as: :worker)  # Number of workers = 3

...

pool.size = 2        # Change number of pooled workers from 3 to 2
```